# Problems defining variable in click event

Tags: jquery

I have dynamically created classes called `.floor1`, `.floor2` and etc.
I want to add a click listener to those but having problems with the variable in it. I also need the click event for the class .outgrid.

```
$(document).on('click','.outgrid, .floor'+$floorNo, function(e){
    // happens on click
});
```

where `$floorNo` is a global variable.

This code

```
$(document).on('click','.outgrid, .floor1', function(e){
    // happens on click
});
```

works but it has to be with a variable.

Seems to be a quoting mistake but I can't resolve it...

Comment: [Can you reproduce the problem?](http://jsfiddle.net) Your code syntactically is fine.

Comment: It seems the problem is that the global variable $floorNo gets incremented in another function of another file and the new value somehow doesn't update for the onclick listener. Is this a known issue or just a programming flaw by me?